# jQuery and CSS Animations Choppy in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, animation, hardware-acceleration

I'm working on a [minisite](http://designtheworld.alinsan.net/) that features a lot of jQuery animation. It works fine in Safari, Chrome & IE9, but the animation is really choppy in Firefox (7, 8 & 9) on OSX. I thought CSS animation would be smoother, so I [adapted](http://www.elfortunawe.com/parallax/firefox-desktop/) the iPad version of the site and tried that out in Firefox. It seems just as bad.

I haven't spent a lot of time with Firefox, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Do I need to trigger GPU acceleration (like using translateZ(0) in Webkit,) or is it just used all the time for everything (like IE9?) Is Firefox just not powerful enough, even with the GPU?

I'd really appreciate any help I can get. I'm kind of at the end of my rope on this.

Comment: Just so you know, the animations are slightly choppy for me as well. I'm running Chrome 16 on Win 7 64 bit on a Dual Xeon quad-core + nVidia Quadro system

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a fair amount of looking around and asking questions, it seems that Firefox just doesn't handle DOM animation as well as the other browsers. So it looks like I'll just have to live with choppy Firefox animation.

Comment: I've experienced too much bugs with Firefox lately, we should all abandon the browser.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question was asked years ago but I just stumbled upon it and there is no real answer aside from 'firefox sucks'. The trick to enabling hardware acceleration for animating dom elements in firefox is to add a small rotation along with your translate. For example:

```
@keyframes square-animation {
    0%, 100% {
        transform: translate(600px, 160px) rotate(0.01deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate(355px, 160px) rotate(0.01deg);
    }
}
```

The reason it's choppy is to avoid blurring anything within the div being animated (especially text). While I personally don't think this is the right choice for default behaviour, you can see the reasoning [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739176).

Comment: I _hate_ how this worked, but thank you. This has been an issue in Firefox for years; it's terrible that we have to resort to stuff like this to get animations closer to how they look in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed the animations don't stutter while the firefox is windowed,
>   I am on Win 7 x32. They work out real smooth.

The animations are a little choppy while tranisitions only. Rest is good & that website is an astonishing & amazing work you have done so far!

Comment: Thank you, but the art and concept are the designer's, I just made it move and stuff.