# Child elements refusing to inherit background animation in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have made a strap of hexagon shapes on my website that slowly animate the background color to have a "twinkle" effect. You can see it in action at https://taketwicedailey.com/. I made the hexagon shaped elements using a tutorial I found online. It involves making a rectangle element and then positioning the ::before and ::after options as rhombus shapes at the top and bottom of the rectangle element (If there is a better way, let me know, I am new to web building).

What I then wanted to do is have a forever looping animation of the group of hexagon shapes that changes the background color. Then I wanted to set this animation to start at different times for different elements based on an nth-of-type selector. I developed all of this using Google Chrome, on which it works beautifully with no issues, that you can verify yourself.

The problem comes when you use Firefox. It seems that the animation does not want to be inherited by the ::before and ::after options, which gives a bow-tie looking effect. This seems to have happened in a recent update in Firefox because this was not an issue a while ago. I have tried everything from defining the animation inside the ::before, ::after definition, to using !important flags, but the mechanism behind this apparent bug is far beyond my understanding here.

I included my CSS below, thanks in advance for any help.

```
.hex-group {
  position: absolute;
  top: 470px;
  left: 60%;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -5;
  overflow: visible;
}

.hex {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 76px;
  height: 43.87862px;
  margin: 21.93931px 2px 3.4641px;
  z-index: -6;
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);

  animation-name: pulse;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.hex:before, .hex:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -7;
  width: 53.74012px;
  height: 53.74012px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scaleY(0.57735) rotate(-45deg);

  background-color: inherit !important;

}

.hex:before {
  top: 0;
}

.hex:after {
  top: 43.87862px;
}

.hex:nth-of-type(4n) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.hex:nth-of-type(4n+1){
  animation-delay: -5s;
}

.hex:nth-of-type(4n+2){
  animation-delay: -10s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #55636e;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  75%{
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Firefox CSS animations Choppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937075/jquery-and-css-animations-choppy-in-firefox)

Comment: This is not the same problem, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a legitimate Firefox bug, but for now I have found the following workaround. You can "over-specify" the animation to the ::before and ::after elements like so

```
.hex {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 76px;
  height: 43.87862px;
  margin: 21.93931px 2px 3.4641px;
  z-index: -6;
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);

          animation-name: pulse;
          animation-duration: 15s;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-direction: normal;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.hex:before, .hex:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -5;
  width: 53.74012px;
  height: 53.74012px;
          transform-origin: 0 0;
          transform: scaleY(0.57735) rotate(-45deg);

  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);

          animation-name: pulse;
          animation-duration: 15s;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-direction: normal;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.hex:before {
  top: 0;
}

.hex:after {
  top: 43.87862px;
}


.hex:nth-of-type(4n),
.hex:nth-of-type(4n):before,
.hex:nth-of-type(4n):after {
          animation-delay: 0s;
}

.hex:nth-of-type(4n+1),
.hex:nth-of-type(4n+1):before,
.hex:nth-of-type(4n+1):after {
          animation-delay: -5s;
}

.hex:nth-of-type(4n+2),
.hex:nth-of-type(4n+2):before,
.hex:nth-of-type(4n+2):after {
          animation-delay: -10s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #55636e;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #444;
  }
  75%{
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }
}
```